# Examples of periodic functions without sin or cos in their formulations?

Tags: periodic-functions

I'm trying to find a function f(x) such that NCspline (in Matlab) provides a better interpolation than does the Lagrange polynomial. But this function cannot be a linear combination of the sine and cosine functions (with real coefficients). So, I'm trying to find a periodic function without sin or cos in its "components."

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-sinusoidal_waveform